# My connection string using Windows authentication for SQL Server doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I'm having problems whenever I run my application, it says that the connection is wrong. The error is User '' has failed.

I think I didn't specify the user id and password but I don't know what is the user id and my password.

Here's my connection string

```
public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=PayrollDB;Persist Security Info=True;");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=PayrollDB;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=true;");
```

add Intergrated Security=true to connection string.

Comment: error says "
Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'intergrated security'."

Comment: Change it to Integrated Security. I spelled it incorrectly

Comment: I already tried, no error has found but while running, it instantly stopped and I don't know why :(

Comment: Debug and check for any errors. Are you able to open connection using con.Open()

Comment: Thank you so much :D It is really crucial when you missed the name of the database. VS doesn't even recognize the error and I really need to check each lines of my connection to find the persisting bug. Thank you @Akshey. God bless! + :)

Comment: You are welcome. Just one suggestion : define your connection in a configuration file instead of in code itself and every where in code read it from there

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the connection string attribute: `Integrated Security = true`. And this will work correctly.

Comment: Error says "
Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'intergrated security'."

Answer (score 1):

To allow windows authentication, you need to add integrated security set as tru in your connection string like this:

```
public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=PayrollDB;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=true;");
```

Comment: Error says "
Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'intergrated security'."

Comment: I've fixed the typo. It's `Integrated Security=true`